# Image moves on a website when scrolling over

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

How can I make image move slightly on a website, when I’m scrolling over it.

Apple has done so in many places at their site.

http://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/

Ie. Go to iPad Pro site and scroll down to A9X Chip-part. You can see how iPad moves slightly faster than you scroll to scrolling direction. Up or down. Very subtle move but very neat.

So image has to move when it’s in view. I have used code below to add `in-view` class when it's in view and remove it when it's not. Now it need to get it moving based on scrolling...

```js
  var $animation_elements = $('img');
  var $window = $(window);

  function check_if_in_view() {
    var window_height = $window.height();
    var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
    var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

    $.each($animation_elements, function() {
      var $element = $(this);
      var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
      var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
      var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

      //check to see if this current container is within viewport
      if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
        (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
        $element.addClass('in-view');
      } else {
        $element.removeClass('in-view');
      }
    });
  }

  $window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
  $window.trigger('scroll');
```

Comment: Try googling "Parallax Scrolling"

Comment: Get their position, get current scroll position, then onscroll check if they are somehow similar then trigger moving. Everything in js and can be extended with css. If you expect us to provide you code even if we can see that you didn't do anything by yourself... Nope.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: My bad, added code I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that skrollr.js is perfect plugin for this. Here is link to pen I created for demo.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaVMeN

and script

```
skrollr.init({
  forceHeight: false,
  smoothScrollingDuration: 1000
});
```

You can get skrollr here:
https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr